# Get the bit number that differs between two (binary) numbers

Tags: python, math, binary

I have two numbers (binary or not, does not play any role) which differ in just one bit, e.g. (pseudocode)

```
a = 11111111
b = 11011111
```

I want a simple python function that returns the bit position that differs ('5' in the given example, when seen from right to left). My solution would be (python)

```
math.log(abs(a-b))/math.log(2)
```

but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this (without using floats etc.).

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: Try with bitwise XOR instead of abs(a-b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the binary exclusive:

```
a = 0b11111111
b = 0b11011111

diff = a^b  # 0b100000
diff.bit_length()-1 # 5 (the first position (backwards) which differs, 0 if a==b )
```

Comment: Use `(a^b).bit_length() - 1` instead of the string length.(Should work in python2.7+).

Comment: A one line solution is the best. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex `(a^b).bit_length()-1` :)

Answer (score 0):

Without using bitwise operations you could do something like this:

```
In [1]: def difbit(a, b):
   ...:     if a == b: return None
   ...:     i = 0
   ...:     while a%2 == b%2:
   ...:         i += 1
   ...:         a //= 2
   ...:         b //= 2
   ...:     return i
   ...: 

In [2]: difbit(0b11111111, 0b11011111)
Out[2]: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

unless i am missing something...

this should work:

```
>>> def find_bit(a,b):
    a = a[::-1]
    b = b[::-1]
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            return i
    return None

>>> a = "11111111"
>>> b = "11011111"
>>> find_bit(a,b)
5
```

maybe not so elegant, but its easy to understand, and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(a^b).bit_length()-1` is perfect for numbers which have only one difference bit. EX:

```
a = 1000000
b = 1000001
(a^b).bit_length()-1
Output: 0
```

But for numbers which have multiple difference bits, it gives the index of left most difference bit. EX:

```
a = 111111111111111111111111111111
b = 111111110111011111111111111111
c = a^b   # 1000100000000000000000
c.bit_length()-1
Output: 21  # Instead of 17. 21 is the left most difference bit
```

So to solve this problem we need to isolate the right most set bit and then get its index. Thus, using `((a^b) & (-(a^b))).bit_length()-1` works best for all inputs:

```
c = (a^b) & (-(a^b))   # 100000000000000000 - Isolates the rightmost set bit
c.bit_length()-1
Output: 17
(a^b) & (-(a^b))).bit_length()-1
Output: 17
```

Learn about isolating right most set bit from [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/)

Comment: I have tested the results of my answer and it working properly.